# numpy.r_ place the the 1’s in the mid

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading [numpy.r_  docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy.r_).  I get it that I cannot place the 1’s at the mid position.
For example ,

`a = np.array( [[3,4,5],[ 33,44,55]])`

`b = np.array( [[-3,-4,-5],[ -33,-44,-55]])`

`np.r_['0,3,1',a,b]`

Actually firstly the shape (2,3) of `a` is upgraded to shape (1,2,3) and the same  as `b`.Then plus the two shape (1,2,3) + (1,2,3) = (2,2,3) is the final shape of result, note I only plus the first number since the '0' in the '0,3,1'.

Now the question is that according the docs, I can upgrade the shape of  `a` to shape(1,2,3) or (2,3,1) ,but how can upgrade to the shape (2,1,3) ?

Comment: IIUC https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [381]: a = np.array( [[3,4,5],[ 33,44,55]]) 
     ...:  
     ...: b = np.array( [[-3,-4,-5],[ -33,-44,-55]]) 
     ...:  
     ...: np.r_['0,3,1',a,b]                                                    
Out[381]: 
array([[[  3,   4,   5],
        [ 33,  44,  55]],

       [[ -3,  -4,  -5],
        [-33, -44, -55]]])
```

Your question should have displayed this result.  It helps the reader visualize the action, and better understand your question.  Not everyone can run your sample (I couldn't when I first read it on my phone).

You can do the same concatenation with `stack` (or even `np.array((a,b))`):

```
In [382]: np.stack((a,b))                                                       
Out[382]: 
array([[[  3,   4,   5],
        [ 33,  44,  55]],

       [[ -3,  -4,  -5],
        [-33, -44, -55]]])
```

`stack` with axis produces what you want (again, a good question would display the desired result):

```
In [383]: np.stack((a,b), axis=1)                                               
Out[383]: 
array([[[  3,   4,   5],
        [ -3,  -4,  -5]],

       [[ 33,  44,  55],
        [-33, -44, -55]]])
```

We can add the dimension to `a` by itself with:

```
In [384]: np.expand_dims(a,1)                                                   
Out[384]: 
array([[[ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[33, 44, 55]]])
In [385]: _.shape                                                               
Out[385]: (2, 1, 3)
```

`a[:,None]` and `a.reshape(2,1,3)` also do it.

As you found, I can't do the same with `np.r_`:

```
In [413]: np.r_['0,3,0',a].shape                                                
Out[413]: (2, 3, 1)
In [414]: np.r_['0,3,1',a].shape                                                
Out[414]: (1, 2, 3)
In [415]: np.r_['0,3,-1',a].shape                                               
Out[415]: (1, 2, 3)
```

Even looking at the code it is hard to tell how `r_` is handling this 3rd parameter.  It looks like it uses the `ndmin` parameter to expand the arrays (which prepends new axes if needed), and then some sort of transpose to move the new axis.

This could be classed as bug in `r_`, but it's been around so long, I doubt if any one will care.  It's more useful for expanding "slices" than for fancy concatenation.

While the syntax of `np.r_` may be convenient on occasion, it isn't an essential function.  It's just another front end to `np.concatenate` (with the added `arange/linspace` functionality).